# How to secure Elmah with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack, elmah

Since Elmah relies on ASP.NET security the following web.config section does not work with ServiceStack authorizations:

```
<location path="admin">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

So, what is the best practice to lock `elmah.axd` to everyone except administrators users?

Comment: Finally I ended up doing my own implementation of log.axd and deactivating it. Thus, I now have a ElmahService (ServiceStack service) with requests ErrorLog.GetDefault(request.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context).GetErrors(pageIndex, request.Rows, errors) and returns a List<ErrorLogEntry> instance which I format on a razor view. This way, I can control security better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run ServiceStack with MVC you should typically define ServiceStack to pick up the requests to a custom location such as `api` using `<location path="api">`.

See here for setup instructions:

- [ServiceStack v3 (BSD)](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework)
- [ServiceStack v4 (Commercial)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework)

Therefore ServiceStack won't handle requests to other locations and as such the location path `<location path="admin">` will be outside the path handled by ServiceStack, so the Authentication of your `elmah.axd` will be handled by IIS. So IIS will authenticate as per usual.